# Chrome: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I hit a break point in dev tools and I inspect the variable 'LoggingSystem":

```html
private initialise = () => {
            var menuHtml = "";
            for (let item of LoggingSystem.getDefault().UserPrivilegeList) {
              if (item.ScreenId != 4) { //this is hit ok, and item has the right information
```

I see the "Syntax error..." message with the stack:

```html
"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at MenuController.initialise (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/es/MenuController.js:12:30)
    at new MenuController (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/es/MenuController.js:118:18)
    at LoggingSystem.loadedCallBack (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Logging/Festival?festivalId=9:203:26)
    at Object.success (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/es/LoggingSystem.js:186:39)
    at fire (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3268:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:3398:7)
    at done (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:9305:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (http://localhost/LoggingWebApp/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js:9548:9)"
```

The code runs ok, and it is only if i inspect the variable i can see that error.

The getDefault is a static method in the LoggingSystem class

```html
 
 private static defaultModel: any;
 
 static getDefault = () => {
            return LoggingSystem.defaultModel;
        }
```

Any ideas where I went wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Clearly you're storing that string (which is an error message) in the variable. So...I'd look at where you're doing that (which is in a `done` handler on a jQuery ajax operation).

Comment: The issue is with one of the item in "UserPrivilegeList". Please do console.log(item) inside for loop, then you will be able to get to root cause